# Json doesn't parse everything

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON response like :

```
    {
"stepLang":"en",
"isFromCache":true,
"isInNotebook":false,
"standardQuery":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"relatedProblems":[
],
"subject":"Algebra",
"topic":"Inequalities",
"subTopic":"PolynomialIneqSolver",
"solutions":[
{
"step_input":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"entire_result":"-3\\le x\\le 4",
"solvingClass":"Inequalities",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0{\\quad:{\\quad}\\begin{bmatrix}\\mathrm{Solution:} \u0026 -3\\le x\\le 4 \\\\ \\mathrm{Interval Notation:}\u0026 [-3,4]\\end{bmatrix}"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"step_input":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"isLocked":true,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Find the signs of the factors of }(x-4)(x+3)"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Find the signs of }x-4"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"step_input":"x-4\u003d0",
"entire_result":"x\u003d4",
"solvingClass":"Equations",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x-4\u003d0:{\\quad}x\u003d4"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x-4+4\u003d0+4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Add }4\\mathrm{ to both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003d4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
},
{
"step_input":"x-4\u003c0",
"entire_result":"x\u003c4",
"solvingClass":"Inequalities",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x-4\u003c0:{\\quad}x\u003c4"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x-4+4\u003c0+4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Add }4\\mathrm{ to both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003c4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
},
{
"step_input":"x-4\u003e0",
"entire_result":"x\u003e4",
"solvingClass":"Inequalities",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x-4\u003e0:{\\quad}x\u003e4"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x-4+4\u003e0+4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Add }4\\mathrm{ to both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003e4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
}
]
},
{
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Find the signs of }x+3"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"step_input":"x+3\u003d0",
"entire_result":"x\u003d-3",
"solvingClass":"Equations",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x+3\u003d0:{\\quad}x\u003d-3"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x+3-3\u003d0-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Subtract }3\\mathrm{ from both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003d-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
},
{
"step_input":"x+3\u003c0",
"entire_result":"x\u003c-3",
"solvingClass":"Inequalities",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x+3\u003c0:{\\quad}x\u003c-3"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x+3-3\u003c0-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Subtract }3\\mathrm{ from both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003c-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
},
{
"step_input":"x+3\u003e0",
"entire_result":"x\u003e-3",
"solvingClass":"Inequalities",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"x+3\u003e0:{\\quad}x\u003e-3"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"entire_result":"x+3-3\u003e0-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Subtract }3\\mathrm{ from both sides}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003e-3",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Simplify}"
}
}
}
]
}
]
}
]
},
{
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Summarize in a table:}"
}
},
"explanation":[
{
"createdText":"\\begin{table} \u0026x\u003c-3\u0026x\u003d-3\u0026-3\u003cx\u003c4\u0026x\u003d4\u0026x\u003e4\u0026\\\\x-4\u0026-\u0026-\u0026-\u00260\u0026+\u0026\\\\x+3\u0026-\u00260\u0026+\u0026+\u0026+\u0026\\\\(x-4)(x+3)\u0026+\u00260\u0026-\u00260\u0026+\u0026\\\\\\summaryline\\end{table}"
}
]
},
{
"entire_result":"x\u003d-3\\lor -3\u003cx\u003c4\\lor x\u003d4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":true,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Identify the intervals that satisfy the required condition:} \\le 0"
}
}
},
{
"entire_result":"-3\\le x\\le 4",
"isInterimStep":true,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":true,
"isLocked":true,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{Merge Overlapping Intervals}"
}
},
"steps":[
{
"image":"/images/interval?expression\u003d%28y_%7B0%7D%3D-3%29%5Clor+%28-3%3Cy_%7B0%7D%3C4%29",
"entire_result":"-3\\le x\u003c4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{The union of two intervals is the set of numbers which are in either interval}\u003cbr/\u003ex\u003d-3\\quad\\mathrm{or}\\quad -3\u003cx\u003c4"
}
}
},
{
"image":"/images/interval?expression\u003d%28-3%5Cle+y_%7B0%7D%3C4%29%5Clor+%28y_%7B0%7D%3D4%29",
"entire_result":"-3\\le x\\le 4",
"isInterimStep":false,
"isOpen":false,
"isShowSolutionAfterStep":false,
"title":{
"text":{
"createdText":"\\mathrm{The union of two intervals is the set of numbers which are in either interval}\u003cbr/\u003e-3\\le x\u003c4\\quad\\mathrm{or}\\quad x\u003d4"
}
}
}
]
}
],
"practiceLink":"/practice/inequalities-practice#area\u003dmain\u0026subtopic\u003dQuadratic",
"practiceTopic":"Polynomial Inequalities"
}
],
"plotInfo":{
"variable":"x",
"funcsToDraw":{
"funcs":[
{
"evalFormula":"x\u003d-3",
"displayFormula":"x\u003d-3",
"attributes":{
"color":"BLACK",
"lineType":"NORMAL",
"labels":[
],
"isAsymptote":false
}
},
{
"evalFormula":"x\u003d4",
"displayFormula":"x\u003d4",
"attributes":{
"color":"BLACK",
"lineType":"NORMAL",
"labels":[
],
"isAsymptote":false
}
}
],
"attributeFactory":{
"color":"PURPLE",
"lineType":"NORMAL",
"labels":[
],
"isAsymptote":false
}
},
"linesToDraw":[
],
"fills":[
{
"ranges":[
{
"fst":"-3.0",
"snd":"4.0"
}
],
"funcIndices":[
],
"funcs":[
],
"xIneq":true,
"yIneq":false,
"twoVar":false,
"trueAboveLine":false,
"color":"rgba(171, 181, 235, 0.3)"
}
],
"functionChanges":[
{
"origFormulaLatex":[
],
"finalFormulaLatex":[
],
"plotTitle":"-3\\le x\\le 4",
"paramsLatex":[
],
"paramsReplacementsLatex":[
]
}
],
"localBoundingBox":{
"xMin":-5.0,
"xMax":6.0,
"yMin":-2.0,
"yMax":8.0
},
"graphCalcInputErrors":[
],
"intervals":[
{
"mind":-3.0,
"maxd":4.0,
"minInclusive":true,
"maxInclusive":true,
"maxFinite":true,
"minFinite":true,
"isAllR":false,
"isPoint":false
}
],
"isInCache":false,
"imageAPI":"-3\\le x\\le 4"
},
"numberLineInfo":{
"imageAPI":"/images/numberLine?xmin\u003d-5.0\u0026xmax\u003d6.0\u0026expression\u003d-3%5Cle+y_%7B0%7D%5Cle+4"
},
"dym":{
"inputEquation":"\\left(x-4\\right)\\left(x+3\\right)\\le 0",
"originalEquation":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"outEquation":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"dymEquation":"(x-4)(x+3)\\le 0",
"isTemplate":false,
"showDidYouMean":false,
"showInstead":false
}
```

i tried to parse it using Newtonsoft.Json and code

```
string NotParsedResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // json above
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(NotParsedResponse);
foreach (dynamic step in dynObj.solutions)
{
    foreach (dynamic step1 in step.steps)
    {
        Result += @" \\\ " + step1.title + @" \\\ " + step1.entire_result + @" \\\ " + step1.step_input ;
    }
}
```

I want to get everything after  title , step_input , entire_result.But it doesn't return it correct.
So i decided to change code like :

```
foreach (dynamic step in dynObj.solutions.steps)
{
  Result += step.step_input;
}
```

I got exception 
**Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'steps''**

Comment: There is no entry called `steps` inside `solutions`. Did you do a typo ?

Comment: What is your goal? is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried to get  step_input,title fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`solutions` is an array according to the JSON you specified.

Could you also create binding object out of this JSON? The data doesnt seem to be unstructured and its easier to work with!

```cs
var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(NotParsedResponse);

public class Root
{
  public List<Step> solutions { get;set; }

  public class Step 
  {
    public string step_input { get; set; }
    // rest of properties
  }
}
```

--Edit
The first object inside `solutions` array contains very nested structure:

```
{
 "steps: [
  ...
  {
   ...
   "steps": [
    ...
    {
     ...
     "steps" : [
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

If that's the case you have to change structure to :

```
public class Root
{
  public List<Step> solutions { get;set; }

  public class Step 
  {
    public string step_input { get; set; }
    // rest of properties
    public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Im not sure if that will work out

```
foreach(var step in dynObj.solutions) {
 if(step.steps != null) {
  ... another loop
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to loop all steps

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: foreach(var step1 in step.steps)
                    {
                        Result += step1.step_input;
                    } something like this

Answer (score 0):

Based on the json you provided. It should be more like

```
foreach (dynamic step in dynObj.solutions)
{
   Result += step.step_input;
}
```

Comment: No,I want to loop steps in solutions

Comment: Ok things got clearer after putting the json in a json formatter ... you need to recursively loop over element inside steps.

Comment: @log0 ...but not using a dynamic, though: the schema is unclear and the first attempt to access the "steps" where is not, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the above JSON is missing the closing bracket, but it could be a problem of copy-and-paste in the post.

Secondly, the first snippet is formally correct if seen from the incoming JSON: you have a `solution`, which is an array, and you must iterate on it or get the only item in it.

Comment: yes but it doesnt loop all steps

Comment: you mean that you want to iterate over *all nested* steps? there are plenty of "steps"!

Comment: Yes i want to loop all steps

Comment: hmm...I think it would be hard with a dynamic object, then. Why not walking the JSON with JLinq? it would be way easier...

Comment: any suggestions how to get title field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use recursion to store all inputs and results.

```cs
foreach (var step in dynObj.solutions)
    {
        if (step.steps != null)
        {
            Print(step.steps);
        }
    }

public void Print(IEnumerable<Step> steps)
{
    foreach(var step in steps)
    {
        var title = $"title: {step?.title?.text?.createdText ?? string.Empty}";
        var txt = $"input: {step.step_input ?? string.Empty}";
        var res = $"result: {step.entire_result ?? string.Empty}";
        //Add to array 

        if(step.steps!=null && step.steps.Any()){
            Print(step.steps);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats work but i used nested foreach Thanks for answer

Comment: Also in steps there is "title" field how can get value of it

Comment: I updated the solution with title property I hope that will help.